# Is there a way to have a TextInput instance do on_text_validate if focus = False?

Tags: python, kivy

So I have a TextInput instance and I would like it to do self.dispatch('on_text_validate') if the focus goes from True to False.

Basically if I do not click enter, where multiline = False, or tab, where write_tab = False, but instead do 'on_text_validate' if the user clicks somewhere else on the screen and the focus for the TextInput is lost.

I am still new to kivy. Is the way to do this with callbacks somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will dispatch `on_text_validate` event when the text input loses its focus:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyTextInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.register_event_type('on_text_validate')

    def on_text_validate(self):
        print 'on_text_validate dispatched'

    def on_focus(self, obj, focused):
        if not focused:
            self.dispatch('on_text_validate')
```

Comment: Awesome thanks so much. I have been trying to figure this out for awhile now.